# Javascript select input type file

Tags: html, file-upload, browser, window, dom-events

I wanted to activate an input type=file (opening the file selection window) by using an onclick event on an image. I tried using the html label tag, however, this doesn't work in IE and Safari. This is the form I'm using.

```
<form id="MyForm" action="Thispage.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="ImageFile"/>
</form>
```

I first tried this:

```
<label for="ImageFile"><img src="MyImage.jpg"></label>
<!--This didn't worked in IE and Safari-->
```

I thought I could do it with an onclick event like this:

```
<img src="MyImage" onclick="Javascript:document.getElementById('ImageFile').click()">
```

This unfortunately didn't worked in Safari.

Is there any method that works in all browsers?

I would like a detailed explanation, because I'm not an expert. It helps me understand which code leads to which action.

Answer (score 1):

Change the "Id" to "name" and try again.

I do not have the safari here, but in all other worked perfectly.

Try this:

```
<input type='file' name='nameFile'>
```

Or if you prefer, look: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

This site is a great reference.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do I use the name of the input? I've found a method using getElementsByName(), but it didn't worked in firefox.